# Rubocop Rails/UniqueValidationWithoutIndex overfiring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop, unique-index

I am getting the following lint error from Rubocopy:

```
app/models/slack_profile.rb:3 W: Rails/UniqueValidationWithoutIndex: Uniqueness validation should be with a unique index.
```

This corresponds to a uniqueness validation on the `slack_user_id` column of this model:

```rb
class SlackProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :slack_user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

This is, this model *does* have a unique index, as evidenced here in `schema.rb`

```rb
  create_table "slack_profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id",       limit: 4,   null: false
    t.string  "slack_user_id", limit: 255, null: false
  end

  add_index "slack_profiles", ["slack_user_id"], name: "index_slack_profiles_on_slack_user_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "slack_profiles", ["user_id"], name: "index_slack_profiles_on_user_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Am I missing something here? Is there something else I need to get a proper unique index?

Comment: Did you every find out why this happened? I just ran into the same issue.

Comment: I recall concluding there was a set of versions of rubocop subject to this as an error, but I don't recall. I do know that we're not seeing this anymore. If I re-discover more detail on a second look, i'll be back here with an update